# Есть ли способ считать переменную другого процесса без ReadProcessMemory? C++

Tags: c++, winapi, память

В WinApi есть функция `ReadProcessMemory`, которая позволяет считать переменную из памяти другого процесса.
Я пишу свой отладчик и мне нужно выводить на экран значение конкретной переменной в режиме реального времени. То есть если переменная меняется, то тут же меняется и переменная на экране.
Загвоздка в том, что для считывания значения нужно обращаться к системе через `ReadProcessMemory`, что мне кажется очень не быстрым способом и могут быть сильные просадки по производительности, если постоянно применять эту функцию для мониторинга переменных. Есть ли способ считать значение переменной быстро, если я уже знаю ее адрес в виртуальном пространстве другого процесса?

Comment: Для этого надо определить места, из которых данные могут изменяться, поставить в них точки останова, а потом обработать их срабатывания. Возможно прокатит создание аппаратной остановки через отладочный регистр на запись см https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register

Comment: @user7860670 благодарю. Но разве точки останова не будут прерывать выполнение другого процесса?

Comment: конечно будет, в этом-то и смысл

Comment: @user7860670 понятно. Но я имел ввиду мониторинг переменной в памяти процесса без остановки. То есть программа выполняется и на протяжении всей ее жизни (упрощенно) я могу видеть изменение переменной

Comment: Это предполагает, что каждое изменение будет отслеживаться и выполняться какие-либо действия.